# Dynamic Number of Tables with dynamic number of columns and rows - R Shiny

Tags: r, dataframe, input, dynamic, shiny

I have a code that generates dataframes based on user inputs. 
Please find attached my code.

```
library(shiny)

runApp(list(
ui = pageWithSidebar(
headerPanel("test"),
sidebarPanel(
  numericInput("number","Input No. of tables",value = 1,min=1),
  numericInput("rows","Input No. of rows",value = 1,min=1),
  numericInput("col","Input No. of cols",value = 1,min=1)),


mainPanel(
  column(tableOutput("value"), width = 1))
),   
server = function(input,output){
observe({
  if (input$number == 0) 
    return()
  isolate({
    output$value <-renderTable({
      num.inputs.col1 <- paste0("<input id='c1n", 1:input$rows, "' class='shiny-bound-input' type='number' value='1'>")
      lapply(seq(input$number), function(l){
        data.frame(EXPERT = replicate(input$col,num.inputs.col1))
      })}, sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)
  })
})
}
))
```

My problem is that i would like to show every new table in different line (below) and not in the same with the previous one.

Is this possible?

Also how can i access these inputs?

Thank you in advance

**EDIT**

PoGibas thank you,

Do you mean something like this?

```
library(shiny)

runApp(list(
ui = pageWithSidebar(
 headerPanel("test"),
sidebarPanel(
  numericInput("number","Input No. of tables",value = 1,min=1),
  numericInput("rows","Input No. of rows",value = 1,min=1),
  numericInput("col","Input No. of cols",value = 1,min=1)),


mainPanel(
  column(tableOutput("value"), width = 1))
),   
server = function(input,output){
 observe({
   if (input$number == 0) 
     return()
   isolate({
     output$value <-renderUI({
      num.inputs.col1 <- paste0("<input id='c1n", 1:input$rows, "' class='shiny-bound-input' type='number' value='1'>")
      lapply(seq(input$number), function(l){
        renderTable({
        data.frame(EXPERT= replicate(input$col,num.inputs.col1))
      },sanitize.text.function = function(x){x})})} )
  })
})
}
))
```

Do you know how can i access the inputs, and how can i change the names of the tables?

Comment: You're rendering one table, not multiple - you have to change your strategy (probably with `renderUI`)

Comment: Please see my edit!